# blenc_encrypt - php-cgi process is crashing

Tags: php, fastcgi, lighttpd, blenc

I'm using blenc function to encrypt some PHP code.

The environment is the following :

- Lighttpd as web server with fastcgi module enabled
- Key stored into /usr/local/etc/blenckeys
- An encrypted PHP script which can be used in cli or web mode
- The php.ini is exactly the same between cgi and cli

**If I use the encrypted script in cli mode, no problem occured**.

If I'm using the same encrypted script through lighttpd (cgi) I get a 500 Internal error -

**the first call of http://x.x.x.x/myscript.php works, but the following will failed with this error** :

> 2016-03-09 08:48:45: (mod_fastcgi.c.2562) unexpected end-of-file
>   (perhaps the fastcgi process died): pid: 1886 socket:
>   unix:/tmp/php.socket-0 
>       2016-03-09 08:48:45: (mod_fastcgi.c.3346) response not received, request sent: 1078 on socket: unix:/tmp/php.socket-0 for
>   /myscript.php, closing connection

**EDIT**

Thanks to my colleague, I found the issue and know how to fix this.

The problem comes from Zend OPcache which is not compatible with blenc extension.

```
[opcache]
; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=0
```

**EDIT**

Sure I can share a part of the code :

In the packaging (the place where I encrypt the code), I store the redistribution key into a 'ekey' file :

As I'm using the same key to all encrypted files, the redistribution key is the same for all files :

```
$encryptionKey = md5("myApp".rand (1, 65534).time());
if ($obfuscate) {
    $redistributionKey = blenc_encrypt("someText", "/tmp/ekey", $encryptionKey);
    file_put_contents(__DIR__."/ekey", $redistributionKey);
}
```

Next step is encrypting the files using the same `$encryptionKey` - PHP tags are stripped :

```
$oFileNoTags = preg_replace(array('/^<(\?|\%)\=?(php)?/', '/(\%|\?)>$/'), array('',''), $oFile);
if (function_exists("blenc_encrypt")) {
    $redistributionKey = blenc_encrypt($oFileNoTags, $destFolder.basename($file), $encryptionKey);
} else {
    $this->errror(570, "blenc_encrypt function not available. Please install first using PECL");
}
```

Last, when installing new package on clients, the 'ekey' file is read and **overwrite** existing key :

```
$newKeyEncryptionValue = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/ekey");
if (strpos($keyFileContent, $newKeyEncryptionValue) === false) {
    // file_put_contents($keyFile, $newKeyEncryptionValue."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    $this->system("echo '".$newKeyEncryptionValue."' | sudo tee ".$keyFile);
}
```

I guess there is a bug with blenc and fast-cgi I can't explained or maybe something misconfigured.

Comment: Don't keep adding answers, add additional ind=formation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I read in another SO question on time that blenc had issues. Without being able to see your code though I can't confirm this. Apparently the PHP doc's show the wrong code (and I can confirm it's still wrong as I checked just now). So I'm going to assume you're using the code in the PHP docs which is wrong. Instead of:

```
file_put_contents($key_file, $redistributable_key, FILE_APPEND);
```

You should be using:

```
file_put_contents($key_file, $redistributable_key."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Which will explain why your script works the first time but not the second. The first code example writes all of the keys to to same line, rather than a new line, which corrupts the keys.

Comment: The problem does not comes from the key, I was aware of the doc mistake. I just write one key into key file to avoid warnings. In CLI mode, the encrypted script work each times. What I mean by "it works only the first time" is the following : I start lighttpd server. Call the script page => it works. Then I do a CTRL+R to refresh page => got a 500 error.

Comment: Any chance you can share you actual PHP code so we stand a chance of figuring out what's wrong?